# Docker volume mount: "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker

I'm pretty new to Docker and trying to get my first (real) image up-and-running. I've written my Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /myapp
VOLUME /myapp/configuration
VOLUME /etc/asterisk
VOLUME /usr/share/asterisk/sounds
```

So my container should start in `/myapp` and I should be able to mount external volumes to configure my app (`configuration`), Asterisk and its sounds.

Though, when I start a container with my image:

```
docker run -it \
--entrypoint /bin/bash myapp \
-v $(pwd)/asterisk:/etc/asterisk \
-v $(pwd)/configuration:/myapp/configuration \
-v $(pwd)/asterisk/sounds:/usr/share/asterisk/sounds
```

It gives me the following error:

```
/bin/bash: /home/me/Docker/asterisk:/etc/asterisk: No such file or directory
```

I really don't understand why. I've verified it was not a line-ending issue (`CRLF` rather than expected `LF` for example), and it's not. I really don't know.

If it counts, I'm running elementary OS Loki.

Please suggest.

Comment: As a side note: `--mount` should be preferred over `-v` (introduced with Docker 17.06). See the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) for more information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found what the problem was, my hint was the unusual `/bin/bash` beginning the line.

Actually, it was interpreting my `-v` options as options for the entrypoint, and bash didn't understand it.

I moved my lines (`--entrypoint` is now the last option) and it works like a charm.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the volume mount coming after a `--name [name]` field.